# Конвертация NVARCHAR в DATETIME в MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица курсов валюты за 5 лет. Левая колонка состоит из дат. Импорт делался из файла формата `csv` и эти даты в формате `NVARCHAR`. Необходимо их преобразовать в формат `DATETIME` (или `DATE`). У меня получается конвертировать только даты с 1 по 12 число месяца, остальные остаются. Проблема, вероятно, кроется в формате представления данных `mm.dd.yyyy` или `dd.mm.yyyy`. Но я менял эти форматы в менеджере - результат такой же. Использую `Dbeaver`, `SQL-server-linux` на `Docker`. Где мне еще поменять формат представления в системе, чтоб он совпадал с имеющимся в таблице. В таблице даты в виде `dd.mm.yyyy`. Я использую следующий скрипт для преобразования из `NVARCHAR` в `DATETIME`

```
UPDATE Rates SET Col1 = CASE WHEN ISDATE(Col1) = 1
             THEN 
               CONVERT(nvarchar(255),
                 CAST(Col1 AS datetime), 104)
             END WHERE ISDATE(Col1) = 1;
```

Comment: Зачем cast внутри convert?

Comment: Сейчас в таблице `dd.mm.yyyy`.

Comment: Попробуйте так CONVERT(datetime, Col1, 104)

Comment: Пробовал. Благодарю за ответы всех. Уже исправил ситуацию (ответ ниже).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема у вас в проверке ISDATE(Col1). Она берет настройки по умолчанию и пытается проверить, является ли строка датой. Т.к. по умолчанию у вас настройки именно mm.dd.yyyy, то даты более 12 не распознаются как даты.

Основная рекомендация - убрать эту проверку, и использовать более умную функцию TRY_CONVERT с нужными вам параметрами, если позволяет версия сервера.

Если версия не позволяет, используйте одну из двух настроек:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
```

переведет ваш формат в dd.mm.yyyy,

```
SET LANGUAGE russian;
```

установит языком по-умолчанию русский, в нем формат тоже dd.mm.yyyy.

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT` делает тоже самое.

Comment: Спасибо! Второй вариант `SET Language russian` помог.

Answer (score 1):

В таких непонятных случая вместо написания `CASE` можно воспользоваться командой `TRY_CONVERT`: `TRY_CONVERT(datetime, Col1, 104)` при невозможности конвертирования данная функция вернет `NULL`

> TRY_CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ], expression [, style ] )

подробнее можно прочитать [по ссылке](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql)